# 2-3 tree best way to insert some values

Tags: java, tree

For example i have these **int** numbers: [2; 52; 5; 6; 8]

1. which one is the best way to insert for example some int values in specific order for having most possible fewer nodes of 2-3 tree
2. and which way is best to have as much as possible more nodes of 2-3 tree

Comment: guys please help me, im not asking for solving my problem , but just to give me some thoughts